# How to work with external accessory device to play music on the device?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, audio-player, mfi, external-accessory

I am doing preliminary design of an iPhone app so that my app is connecting to non iOS handsfree device or a music system through bluetooth and play songs on it. We registered for the MFi program with Apple and are waiting for confirmation.

If it's possible could you kindly provide few guides to look into it?

Comment: Please don't 'forget' that most of this topics is under NDA.

Comment: hi Rokjarc, thanks for your reponse. I know the MFi is under NDA, I commented to Dennis what I need, what my question is pls provide me a document or shot me a link for start my app thru. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Are you want to connect tv etc device with Iphone/Ipad to remotely control the device and volume? If yes then check the following links, perhaps these will help you.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-TC5uh4j7M

http://thinkflood.com/products/redeye/

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/redeye/id315598320?mt=8
```

Comment: Thanks Khalid, Actually the redeye is works with wifi, my app app requirement is works with bluetooth and play songs which are in the iphone on the car speakers and control it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is - can you clarify.
You don't need MFi if you are doing standard bluetooth - like streaming music, if the music player supports bluetooth A2DP - the iPhone can connect to it and stream music to it out of the box.

Comment: Hi Dennis, Thanks for quick response. the bluetooth device is not a slandered. It is like a car music system so that developing an app that play songs thru the car speakers with play, pause, stop features and moere..

Comment: What standard bluetooth profiles does the car support ? All it needs is to support A2DP and AVRCP and you are set - any iPhone can stream to the car and control the music either from the car or form the music player on the iPhone.

Comment: how to set A2Dp, Actually we plan to buy a software from CSR, so that they provide a board & chip and we install software on it. the app also supports the HFP, and PBAP also. I think the car kit is a non ios device so we make it as MFi right?